# Problem using Render instead of Component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I get this error:
*Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports*

When clicking this link:

```js
<li><NavLink activeClassName="active" to={{pathname: '/add-new'}}>Add new Recipe</NavLink>{' '} </li>
```

My route looks like this:

```js
<PrivateRoute 
  exact 
  path='/add-new' 
  render={(props) => 
    <NewRecipe 
      {...props} 
      addRecipe={this.addRecipe}/>
  } 
  authenticated={authenticated} 
/>
```

PrivateRoute.js looks like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export default function PrivateRoute({
  component: Component,
  authenticated,
  ...rest
}) {
  console.log(...rest);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        authenticated === true ? (
          <Component {...props} {...rest} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Error occurs since I switched from `Component={NewRecipe}` to `Render={...}` since I need to pass a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PrivateRoute` skips `render` props (instead of call it), fix might be something like this (notice `render()` logic):

```js
export default function PrivateRoute({
  component: Component,
  authenticated,
  render,
  ...rest
}) {
return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        authenticated === true ? (
          render ? render(props) : <Component {...props} {...rest} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
```

It's overcomplex a bit, but I hope can help you understand the idea on how `render` prop might be caught.

Other solution is to change `/add-new` to be passed as a component:

```js
  <PrivateRoute 
    exact 
    path='/add-new' 
    addRecipe={this.addRecipe}
    component={NewRecipe}
    authenticated={authenticated} 
  />
```

Comment: I used to pass it as a component but since I use Link to call PrivateRoute I need to pass the function in Render={}

Comment: @indiehjaerta yeah, np, try to update `PrivateRoute` as I suggested

Comment: It get's rid of the error but I think somehow it ain't passing the render correctly cause when it calls addRecipe that is in my App.js this.state is undfined which it is not.

Comment: @indiehjaerta maybe [you've missed to bind the addRecipe](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) to correct context?